# How do I add code to a button inside of an ActiveX Control Frame?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a form inside of a Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame.
[Frame I would like to interact with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp9DH.png)

After setting it up, I can't seem to add code to any of the objects inside of this frame. When I right click on the frame I can view the code for the frame. But whenever I right click on a textbox or button inside the frame, the "view code" option is grayed out.
[View Code not activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uihOL.png)

How do I interact with the objects inside of the frame? For example, the spin button? The code below works whenever the spin button and text box are not inside of the frame. How can I make this code work for the same spin button and textbox that are inside of a frame?

Thank you!

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
If Me.TextBox2 = "" Then Me.TextBox2 = 0
Me.TextBox2 = Me.TextBox2 + 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
If Me.TextBox2 = "" Then Me.TextBox2 = 0
Me.TextBox2 = Me.TextBox2 - 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton11_SpinUp()
If Me.TextBox21 = "" Then Me.TextBox21 = 0
Me.TextBox21 = Me.TextBox21 + 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton11_SpinDown()
If Me.TextBox21 = "" Then Me.TextBox21 = 0
Me.TextBox21 = Me.TextBox21 - 1
End Sub
```

[spin button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSMpU.png)

I tried adding the code here, but this did not work
[VB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45H14.png)
[VB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIQbm.png)

Comment: Following this! I'm having a similar issue.